# How can I calculate the bandwidth of any PHP page in a server?

Tags: php, server, bandwidth

Is there any tool for calculating bandwidth? I have a web page in PHP which is generating json every 10 seconds. I have a web server for PHP and they have given me 2GB (2000 MB) of bandwidth, so I want to know how much memory my page is consuming in 1 hit.

For example, if I have the URL and I hit that URL, is there a tool that will show me how much bandwidth I have used?

Answer (score 0):

Feature you need is called `profiling`. There are some free profilers, and there are also paid.

From paid, you can consider using [Blackfire](https://blackfire.io/). From free, you can try XHProf.

Comment: sir i am very new so and for testing purpose free easy tool